# Change strings incrementally using sed or awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I've a file over 2k lines which looks like:

```
pl (IdPl,X,Y,TitleLine,Name,Description,idRowMetric,idPlMetric,Person) Values (26916,1000,3750,'','','11',null,NULL,1)
pla (IdPl,EncLevel,IdSection) Values (26916,2,21)
pla(IdPl,EncLevel,IdSection) Values (26916,1,1065)

Pl (IdPl,X,Y,TitleLine,Name,Description,idRowMetric,idPlMetric,Person) Values (26917,2900,3750,'','','11',null,NULL,1)
Pla(IdPl,EncLevel,IdSection) Values (26917,2,21)
Pla (IdPl,EncLevel,IdSection) Values (26917,1,1065)

Pl (IdPl,X,Y,TitleLine,Name,Description,idRowMetric,idPlMetric,Person) Values (26918,1050,3750,'','','11',null,NULL,1)
Pla (IdPl,EncLevel,IdSection) Values (26918,2,21)
Pla (IdPl,EncLevel,IdSection) Values (26918,1,1065)

Pl (IdPl,X,Y,TitleLine,Name,Description,idRowMetric,idPlMetric,Person) Values (26919,1100,3750,'','','11',null,NULL,1)
Pla (IdPl,EncLevel,IdSection) Values (26919,2,21)
Pla (IdPl,EncLevel,IdSection) Values (26919,1,1065)
```

How do I replace all 26916 on -1, 26917 on -2 and etc using sed or awk?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Give some examples of what you mean for the search and replace, before and after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sed`:

`sed -r 's/(.*)([0-9]{5})(.*)/echo "\1$((-(\2-26915)))\3"/ge' file`

Comment: Good job Julien :-) Upvoting

Comment: Thanks! :-) It is tricky in `sed` indeed! Upvoted yours already.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I thought that it's not impossible.

Comment: It IS impossible, that script is using bash and echo to do the math, not sed. It will also perform the math on ANY string that is or contains 5 digits, not just the specific number you're interested in.

Comment: Strangely, Ed, it looks like you're trying to make this answer look wrong to make _your_ answer look good ;-)

Comment: Really? Serious question: How do you suggest we point out issues that won't be apparent to the OP given his current sample input but will bite him later given other input? Or should we just ignore those issues and let the OP trip over them some time later while using the tool for his/her job just in case someone reading the comment thinks it was made for some negative reason? Or are you suggesting we should we only point out issues with an answer when we haven't posted an answer that doesn't have those issues?

Comment: True my solution is using `echo`, I think it likely that the OP's system has it (which is not necessarily the case for GNU `awk`, I don't have it). As for the 5 digits string, I assume the format of the 2k lines is the same. There is no foolproof solution for this anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Using `perl` it's very easy:

```
$ perl -pe 's/(2691\d)/ - ( $1 - 26915 ) /e' file
```

This prints to stdout. Redirect it as you need...

Comment: Cool! Thank you a lot for this suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk 'match($0,/(.*\()([0-9]{5})(,.*)/,a) {$0 = a[1] "-" a[2]-26915 a[3]} 1' file
pl (IdPl,X,Y,TitleLine,Name,Description,idRowMetric,idPlMetric,Person) Values (-1,1000,3750,'','','11',null,NULL,1)
pla (IdPl,EncLevel,IdSection) Values (-1,2,21)
pla(IdPl,EncLevel,IdSection) Values (-1,1,1065)

Pl (IdPl,X,Y,TitleLine,Name,Description,idRowMetric,idPlMetric,Person) Values (-2,2900,3750,'','','11',null,NULL,1)
Pla(IdPl,EncLevel,IdSection) Values (-2,2,21)
Pla (IdPl,EncLevel,IdSection) Values (-2,1,1065)

Pl (IdPl,X,Y,TitleLine,Name,Description,idRowMetric,idPlMetric,Person) Values (-3,1050,3750,'','','11',null,NULL,1)
Pla (IdPl,EncLevel,IdSection) Values (-3,2,21)
Pla (IdPl,EncLevel,IdSection) Values (-3,1,1065)

Pl (IdPl,X,Y,TitleLine,Name,Description,idRowMetric,idPlMetric,Person) Values (-4,1100,3750,'','','11',null,NULL,1)
Pla (IdPl,EncLevel,IdSection) Values (-4,2,21)
Pla (IdPl,EncLevel,IdSection) Values (-4,1,1065)
```

With other awks you'd just use substr() instead of the array.